# Python Shopify API add 2 pictures to new product

Tags: python, shopify

I am trying to add 2 pictures to my new shopify store with the api. However, I need to upload 2 pictures not just one. this is what I have so far but its not working please advise.

```
import shopify    
API_KEY = 'dsfsdsdsdsdsad'
PASSWORD = 'sadsdasdasdas'

shop_url = "https://%s:%s@teststore.myshopify.com/admin" % (API_KEY, PASSWORD)
shopify.ShopifyResource.set_site(shop_url)



path = "audi.jpg"
path2 = "audi2.jpg"

new_product = shopify.Product()
new_product.title = "Audi pictures test "
new_product.body_html = "body of the page <br/><br/> test <br/> test"


variant = shopify.Variant({'price': 1.00, 'requires_shipping': False,'sku':'000007'})
new_product.variants = [variant]
image = shopify.Image()
image2 = shopify.Image()



with open(path, "rb") as f:
    filename = path.split("/")[-1:][0]
    filename2 = path2.split("/")[-1:][0]
    encoded = f.read()
    image.attach_image(encoded, filename=filename)
    image2.attach_image(encoded, filename=filename2)

new_product.images = [image,image2]
new_product.save()
```

Answer (score 0):

This code will only upload one image to the Product as you are passing the same encoded value for both the images. I have edited the code below and separated creating Image objects for both the images. This will upload both the images to Shopify.

```
with open(path, "rb") as f:
    filename = path.split("/")[-1:][0]
    encoded = f.read()
    image.attach_image(encoded, filename=filename)

with open(path2, "rb") as f:
    filename2 = path2.split("/")[-1:][0]
    encoded = f.read()
    image2.attach_image(encoded, filename=filename2)
```